# Matching strings that may look like JSON

Tags: php, regex

I have [expression parser](https://github.com/jcubic/expression.php) and I want to add json support so I need to match one of `[` or `{` any number of characters that may include paired `[]` and `{}` and then `]` or `}`.

So far I have `([[{])(.(?!\1))*[\]}]` it match `[foo}` but I can live with that. Invalid json will be catch when json_decode return null.

I need to match JSON in strings like this:

```
{"foo":"bar"} == 20
[1,2,3,4] == 10
```

but also first JSON in those strings:

```
{"foo": "bar"}["foo"]
[1,[2],{"foo":"bar"},4][0]
{"foo": "bar"} == {"foo": "bar"}
```

So far I have regex like this `^([\[{](?>"(?:[^"]|\\")*"|[^\]}]|(?1))*[\]}])`: [demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gVJ) but it don't match:
`[1,[2],{"foo":"bar"},4]`

Comment: Let's ask the obvious: why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: @deceze because I need to extract json from bigger string, I have Expression parser where I want to add support for JSON.

Comment: Yeah, native JSON parsing is the best way to go. Are you trying to do something like this: \[.*\]|\{.*\}

Comment: Is that "bigger string" parsable by a parser? Is there another delimiter in your "bigger string" that would allow you to determine the start and end of embedded JSON? If not, this is a bit of an impossible task unless there are some more constraints.

Comment: @jcubic Please provide us a sample of the text you are working with.

Comment: For example, good luck matching this `{"fo}": "bar[baz}]"}` with a naïve regex…

Comment: @decezeall all you need for that is \{.*\} to at least get a copy of that out of a larger paragraph of text. Since it will automatically match the very first and very last bracket regardless of what's inside.

Comment: The biggest issue with \{.*\} is that it would find only a single match a if there were two sets of JSON. It would take the first bracket of the first set and last bracket of the last set and return everything between

Comment: For something like {"foo": "bar"}["foo"] What are you expecting to match?

Comment: @Asperon the json `{"foo":"bar"}`

Comment: @jcubic Well then \{.*\} is all you need as long as you are sure you won't have something like {"foo":"bar"} == 20 == {"foo":"bar"} Because it won't work in that case, but will work for everything else. here (as long as you go line by line)

Comment: {"foo": "bar"}["foo"]
[1,[2],{"foo":"bar"},4][0] might complicate things if it's being checked all at once. But preg_match does respect new lines so if they were on separate lines it would find a match for each automatically

Comment: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gVI

Comment: @Asperon Unfortunetly I also want to match `{"foo":"bar"} == {"foo": "bar"}` and changing your regex to match arrays `[\{[].*[\}\]]` will match `[1,[2],{"foo":"bar"},4][0]` and not `[1,[2],{"foo":"bar"},4]`

Comment: Yeah, if you are going to have multiple matches that are potentially complicated objects with complicated rules, your regex will end up looking horrific. Your best but inefficient bet is to iterate through the string and compile your json as you loop through it. Unless someone is able to provide a regex example that is fool proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is matching regex I found based on S-Expression regex from comment in this answer [Extract s-expressions from a beginning of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222669/extract-s-expressions-from-a-beginning-of-the-string):

```
^([\[{](?>"(?:[^"]|\\")*"|[^[{\]}]|(?1))*[\]}])
```

https://regex101.com/r/cUkoVe/2

Comment: That will only work if {"foo":"bar"} == {"foo": "bar"} are always the same, if it is ever {"foo2":"bar2"} == {"foo": "bar"} then it won't work

Comment: (?<=\{).*?(?=\}) This does pretty well,but it doesn't include the curly brackets and you need to use preg_match_all