# Extract s-expressions from a beginning of the string

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to match s-expression in the beginning of the string using regex. Like I have string like this:

```
(foo (bar)) "baz" "quux"
```

and I want to extract

```
(foo (bar))
```

it should also able to extract first s-expression from string that look like this:

```
(foo (bar)) (foo bar)
```

and

```
(foo ")" "bar")
```

is it possible using regex?

Comment: Maybe [`^(\((?>"[^"]*"|[^()]|(?1))*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/hQ2hB9/1)?

Comment: Yes that work, thanks. You can add this as an answer.

Comment: @Jan Force of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there are no escape sequences, you may use

```
^(\((?>"[^"]*"|[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ2hB9/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(\((?>"[^"]*"|[^()]|(?1))*\))` - Group 1 whose pattern will be recursed, matching

  - `\(`  - an opening `(`
  - `(?>"[^"]*"|[^()]|(?1))*`  - zero or more occurrences of:

    - `"[^"]*"` - a text starting with `"`, followed with zero or more chars other than `"` and ends with `"`
    - `|` - or
    - `[^()]` - a char other than `(` and `)`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - whole Group 1 pattern (recursion)
- `\)` - a closing `)`.

NOTE: If there can be escaped sequences, it is not a good job for a regex. If you replace `"[^"]*"` with `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`, it would be better, but still not safe.

Comment: @Jan, in this context it is equivalent to a non-capturing group. Atomic groups are those that disallow backtracking into them.

Comment: Speaking about a more "efficient" regex, you may try [`^(\((?>"[^"]*"|[^()"]+|(?1))*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/hQ2hB9/2) (but that will not match `(foo ")" " "bar")` - if it is an invalid s-expr, then it is better, actually.)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient Regular Expression:

```
^(\([^()"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^()"]*)*(?1)*\))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC9zT4/4)

Explanation:

```
^                           # Asserts beginning of line
    (                           # Start of capturing group (1)
        \([^()"]*                   # A sequence of `(...` up to a double quotation mark or `)`
        (?:"[^"]*"[^()"]*)*         # Any string within double quotation marks
        (?1)*                       # Recurs a similar sequence of `(...`
        \)                          # End of match
    )                           # End of capturing group (1)
```

If those patterns that @Wiktor pointed out in comments are valid then this one - however being long - works and keeps efficiency as well:

```
^(\([^()"]*(?1)*[^()"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^()"]*)*(?1)*\))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC9zT4/3) (see number of steps taken by engine)

Comment: It won't work with `(foo ")" " "bar")`, nor with `((a) foo (bar)) "baz" "quux"`

Comment: It's normal. Unbalanced.

Comment: `((a) foo (bar))` is not unbalanced.

Comment: `((a) foo (bar))` syntax is out of patterns.